# Updating Table in Delete Trigger for Multiple Rows Deleted

Tags: t-sql, triggers

I started with the following trigger in SqlServer 2000

```
 ALTER TRIGGER DeleteTrigger
 ON [dbo].[WarrantyClaimsLineItems]
 FOR DELETE
 AS 
 begin

    declare @wa int
    SET @wa = (SELECT warrantyAuthNo from DELETED)
    update dbo.warrantyclaimsauth
    set isused = 0
    WHERE warrantyClaimsAuth.warrantyauthno = @wa


end
```

Basically, whenever a line item is deleted from the table I need to update the warrantyauth.isUsed that was assigned to that line item back to false.

it works when deleting one line item but when multiple line items are deleted I get the following error.

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

I understand why, the trigger is expecting only one record to be deleted. 
so I need to modify it to handle multiple row deletes.

I did some research and modified my trigger to be this

```
....
 AFTER DELETE
 AS 
 begin

    update dbo.warrantyclaimsauth set isUsed = 0
    from dbo.warrantyclaimsauth a
    inner join deleted d on a.warrantyAuthNo = a.warrantyAuthNo


 end
```

this however is updating every row in the warrantyclaimsauth with 0 in the isUsed field.
Can anyone help me with what I am doing wrong? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your join condition is wrong in the second one. Try this:

```
 AFTER DELETE
 AS 
 begin

    update a set isUsed = 0
    from dbo.warrantyclaimsauth a
    inner join deleted d on a.warrantyAuthNo = d.warrantyAuthNo


 end
```

You were joining `deleted` where the `warrantyauthno` equalled itself, rather than the value from the `deleted` table. You were essentially just doing a `cross join` of `deleted` and not filtering any rows what so ever.

Comment: Oh my I am such a dork, I was going crazy and kept overlooking that. Thanks sorry for the dumb issue!

Answer (score 3):

```
inner join deleted d on a.warrantyAuthNo = a.warrantyAuthNo
```

should be

```
inner join deleted d on a.warrantyAuthNo = d.warrantyAuthNo
```

You currently have a trivial join condition giving a cross join which doesn't filter to `deleted`

Answer (score 3):

```
....
 AFTER DELETE
 AS 
 begin

    update dbo.warrantyclaimsauth set isUsed = 0
    from dbo.warrantyclaimsauth a
    inner join deleted d on a.warrantyAuthNo = d.warrantyAuthNo


 end
```